# exercise: dual of an Lp-space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, duality-theorems

I have this exercise:

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be an arbitrary measure space and $1 <p
>  <\infty$. Show that if $l \in \mathcal{L}^p(\mu)^*$, then there exists
>   a sequence $\{\Omega_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of $\mathcal{A}$-measurable
>   sets such that $\mu(\Omega_n)<\infty$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and
>   $l(\mathcal{X}_A)=0$ for each $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that
>   $\mu(A)<\infty$ and $A\subset(\cup_{n=1}^\infty\Omega_n)^c$.

I have no idea of how to define the set $\Omega_n$. My first idea was $\Omega_n=\bigcup\{A | \mu(A)<\infty, |l(\mathcal{X}_A)|<\frac{1}{n}\}$. But two problems arise here, I do not know if the set defined has finite measure, and if K is a subset of that set, it doesnt follow(easily?) that $|l(\mathcal{X}_K)|<1/n$, or is bounded by a number. But the least requirement follows, if a set is in none of the $\Omega_n$, then the linear functional must send the relevant characteristic function to $0$.

So it seems that what I tried made the sets $\Omega_n$ too big.

Can you guys please help?

Comment: Will you assume that the measure space is $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: @JohnMa No, it is the point of the exercise that it is a part of many exercises, where we are trying to extend Riez-representation theorem to arbitrary measure-spaces. Before doing this exercise we have proved Riesz representation for $\sigma$-finite spaces, and this exercises is the first step in proving the Riez-representation theorem for arbitrary measure spaces.